# Dagger 2, зачем генерируемый класс принимает Builder

Tags: android, dagger2

```
public final class DaggerBattleComponent implements BattleComponent {
  private DaggerBattleComponent(Builder builder) {}

  public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
  }

  public static BattleComponent create() {
    return new Builder().build();
  }

  @Override
  public War getWar() {
    return new War(new Starks(), new Boltons());
  }

  public static final class Builder {
    private Builder() {}

    public BattleComponent build() {
      return new DaggerBattleComponent(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Как видно класс  War зависит от классов Starks() и Boltons(). А выше код сгенерированного класса. В Активности код  `BattleComponent component = DaggerBattleComponent.create();` создает экземпляр этого сгенерированного класса. Метод `create()` заставляет создать `DaggerBattleComponent(this);`   В 
 конструкторе `private DaggerBattleComponent(Builder builder) {}`   как видите на вход идет класс Builder, только ничего больше с ним не делается. Зачем его принимал конструктор?

Comment: потому что даггер работает основываясь на паттерне билдер. это единственный способ собрать компоненту.

Comment: Не понимаю.  В конструктор DaggerBattleComponent принимает Builder,   но не использует  принятый аргумент. Зачем тогда он его принимал?

Comment: потому что у вас в билдере нет внешних зависимостей. как только они появятся, то появится и метод initialize() который вытащит поля из билдера и засетит в компоненту